# Is there a public remote testnet node?

Tags: testnet, nodes, remote-access

Similar to this public remote mainnet node?

https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/4jloss/nodemonerohashcom_public_remote_node_for_your/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I couldn't find a public remote testnet node, so I created one on a VPS.

Here's the address...

```
159.203.250.205:38081
```

If you're testing the official CLI wallet, include these options...

```
./monero-wallet-cli --testnet --daemon-address 159.203.250.205:38081
```

If you're testing the official GUI wallet, you need to do the following...

1. open `monero-core.conf`
2. find `daemon_address=localhost:38081`
3. replace with `daemon_address=159.203.250.205:38081`